# How to partial refund the paypal invoice created using Invoicing SDK

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

We are using paypal "CreateAndSendInvoice" function to create and send an invoice,Now we want to  partial refund this invoice once it have been paid(Refund for broken items during shipment)
Is this possible to partially refund invoice payment?

We tried to use Adaptive Payment "Refund" function using "transactionId" parameter but looks like we also need to specify "payKey" or "trackingId" for refund.

Can we use Adaptive Payments function here?
Where we can get these parameters ("payKey" or "trackingId") for invoice as we do not see anything like that in IPN message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the ["RefundTransaction API"](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) for this purpose.